# How do I prevent the child element from escaping from its parent, if translate or matrix values are applied?

Tags: css, css-transforms

For, instance I have an element which have same width and height properties as its parent. I want the parent to contain the child element even if the translate or transform values are applied.

When, I apply x and y properties to the translate or transform the child moves away from its parent. I have tried position values but that doesn't seem to work.

```css
.parent {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ddd;  
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  transform: translate(40px, 40px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
</div>
</div>

<p>how do I restrict the red one within it's parent?</p>
```

Comment: You're explicitly telling it to go outside it's parent, you can apply overflow hidden and hide the overflow, otherwise you can't.

Comment: Yeah, what I meant is, is there any properties in css to prevent it from moving even if the translate values are applied like we prevent top and left? I don't want the child to be hidden but to stay inside.

Comment: How do you prevent top and left ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak If I remove position property, we can prevent it from from escaping if positional values are applied.

Comment: @Ramganesh What do you want to happen instead? Do you want the child's `transform` property to be ignored?

Comment: yes. I want it to be ignored. @MrLister

Comment: @Ramganesh That's not preventing top/left, that's basically not making them apply by removing the environment they need

Comment: Yeah. Is there any way like that for transform properties?

Comment: Nop, all you can do is have a class with `transform:none` and apply it when needed

Comment: I just found a solution. We need to set the top and left values to negative values as in x and y in translate. Like if x=20px and y=20px. Then, we should set left=-20px and right=-20px.

Comment: That is basically undoing what transform does which is equivalent to `transform:none;`

Comment: Nope. It won't remove other properties like scale and rotate though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add overflow property with the value hidden

```css
.parent {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ddd; 

  overflow:hidden;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  transform: translate(40px, 40px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
</div>
</div>

<p>how do I restrict the red one within it's parent?</p>
```